# Batch execute ncap2 command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to batch execute this command

```
ncap2 -s 'where(S<0.005) S=0.005; infile.nc outfile.nc*
```

on all the `nc` files in a folder.

I am using this script:

```
for f in dir/*.nc 
do 
ncap2 -s 'where(S<0.005) S=0.005;' "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

But I am getting this error:

```
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How should I proceed? I am new to scripting.

Update: I am able to perform the operation if I copy-paste the script in the terminal; but running as a script gives error.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: Your script lacks a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: Hi I have made changes after looking at both the links. But it's still not working. Still I am getting the same error at line 5. Here's the new script.         #!/bin/bash
for f in /media/neeldip/PHD/Temporary_Data_transfer/*.nc; do 
 ncap2 -s 'where(S<0.005) S=0.005;' "$f" "${f%.*}"
done

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: Can you **[edit]** this again with the output of `file scriptname` and `cat -v scriptname` (where in each command `scriptname` is replaced by the actual script filename)?